# ValueError: Length mismatch - when tried to read multiple xlsx files with multiple sheets in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I am trying to read multiple `xlsx` files where each has 51 sheets and I want to read, reformat and concatenate them in one dataframe with pandas. However, I am able to read one `xlsx` with 51 sheets correctly but when I use same logic for reading multiple `xlsx` files where each has 51 sheets, I am getting following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [31], in 
> 12 print(names)
> 13 print(len(names))
> ---> 14 src_df = (pd.concat({k: df.assign(State=df.columns[0]).set_axis(['County','Orientation','State'],
> axis=1) for k, df in pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name =
> names).items()}).rename_axis(['ST', None],
> axis=0).reset_index(level=0))
> 15 dfs.append(src_df)
>
> Input In [31], in (.0)
> 12 print(names)
> 13 print(len(names))
> ---> 14 src_df = (pd.concat({k: df.assign(State=df.columns[0]).set_axis(['County','Orientation','State'],
> axis=1) for k, df in pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name =
> names).items()}).rename_axis(['ST', None],
> axis=0).reset_index(level=0))
> 15 dfs.append(src_df) .. ..
>
> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values
> have 3 elements

**my current attempt**:

here are the [example data](https://github.com/adamFlyn/test_rl) that I used for my attempt:

```
VenueMap_Counties_04-02-15.xlsx
VenueMap_Counties_06-13-18.xlsx
VenueMap_Counties_11-04-19.xlsx
```

and here is my attempt to read those `xlsx` files with multiple sheets into one dataframe:

```
files = glob.glob('https://github.com/adamFlyn/test_rl/*.xlsx')
files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']
if len(files_xlsx)>0:
    print("more than one xlsx files found")

# read multiple xlsx files into one
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xlsx:
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    sheetnames = xls.sheet_names[1:]
    print(sheetnames)
    print(len(sheetnames))
    src_df = (pd.concat({k: df.assign(State=df.columns[0]).set_axis(['County','Orientation','State'], axis=1) for k, df in pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name = sheetnames).items()}).rename_axis(['ST', None], axis=0).reset_index(level=0))
    dfs.append(src_df)
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this valueError? Any thoughts?

**desired output**:

in my desired output, I want `Index(['ST', 'County', 'Orientation', 'State'], dtype='object')` as of columns in final dataframe. this is top 5 rows of desired output dataframe:

```
desired_outputDf.head().to_dict()= {'ST': {0: 'AK', 1: 'AK', 2: 'AK', 3: 'AK', 4: 'AK'},
 'County': {0: 'ALEUTIANS EAST',
  1: 'ALEUTIANS WEST',
  2: 'ANCHORAGE',
  3: 'BETHEL',
  4: 'BRISTOL BAY'},
 'Orientaion': {0: 'Plaintiff ',
  1: 'Plaintiff ',
  2: 'Neutral',
  3: 'Plaintiff ',
  4: 'Plaintiff '},
 'State': {0: 'Alaska', 1: 'Alaska', 2: 'Alaska', 3: 'Alaska', 4: 'Alaska'}}
```

Can anyone point me out how to fix this issue? any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: @constantstranger even I manually deleted stray backtick character in column C of the NC sheet in two of three `xlsx` files, I got empty data.frame at the end; Also, technically, I should only read column A and B in each sheet; Do you have possible coding attempts to fix the problem and update your answer? thanks

Comment: I invested time and have answered your original question about how to fix the ValueError. Please consider marking the answer as accepted, which will make it more likely that I will invest additional time in answering your follow-up question. Please note that protocol is ordinarily to pose any follow-up queries as new questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @constantstranger I am not even reading column C in each sheet, how come it caused the issues; plus, what I am asking, how do you detect the backtick character by code or manually looking at it? I know the protocol and I can repost my question with better clarity if you can post your answer later. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why manually clearing out column C eliminated the ValueError. Rather than spend additional time on that, I have updated my answer to include code that I believe will give the dataframe result you want.

Comment: OK, curiosity got the better of me and I looked into why spurious data in column C was giving you a ValueError. For each ST (sheet) you were taking df (2 columns for every state but NC and 3 columns for NC) and assigning a new column State (to make a dataframe that had 3 columns for every state but NC and 4 columns for NC). Then you tried to use `concat` to stack all of these 3 or 4 column dataframes vertically, and this gave you a ValueError if the NC df had a spurious column C, since concat only works with inputs that are homogeneous in shape along the axis of concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of your three xlsx files have a stray backtick character in column C of the NC sheet. Fix these and it should work.

**UPDATE**:

Here is code that should do what you want:

```py
files_xlsx='''
./VenueMap_Counties_04-02-15.xlsx
./VenueMap_Counties_06-13-18.xlsx
./VenueMap_Counties_11-04-19.xlsx
'''.split('\n')[1:-1]
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.concat([
    df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:'County'}).assign(
    State=df.columns[0], ST=ST)[['ST', 'County', 'Orientation', 'State']] for f in files_xlsx for ST, df in pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None).items() if ST != 'Master'])
print(f'shape: {dfs.shape}')
print(dfs.head())
```

Output:

```
shape: (9351, 4)
   ST          County Orientation   State
0  AK  Aleutians East  Plaintiff   Alaska
1  AK  Aleutians West  Plaintiff   Alaska
2  AK       Anchorage     Neutral  Alaska
3  AK          Bethel  Plaintiff   Alaska
4  AK     Bristol Bay  Plaintiff   Alaska
```

Comment: actually I should not read column C, instead I should only read column A and B in each sheet; Can you update your attempt if you have specific coding input? thanks

Comment: In your question, you asked for "ideas how to fix this valueError". I'm just letting you know that I downloaded and edited the files to remove the extraneous character in the NC sheet in two of your files, and that made the error go away. Are you now asking for recommended changes to the code in your question to read only columns A and B instead and to ignore column C, so that you can use the original xlsx files even though they have spurious content?

Comment: I wish I can create reproducible data but `xlsx` file with multple sheets, it is hard to reproduce dummy data and post here; I am sorry for such inconvenience but data has no issues; I understand your concern but still don't get the part that my code should not read column C

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer, which should give the result you want.